# axios react and couchDB

Tags: reactjs, couchdb

In React ,i need to get the data couchDB with axios. I tried this code it does not work.

```
componentWilMount(){
    axios.get('http://localhost:5984/employes', {withCredentials: true}).then(function(data){
      console.log(data)
    })
```

Comment: Does not work *how*?  Error message, incorrect behavior, missing data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest React (v16.10.2), `componentWillMount()` does not exists anymore. It has been renamed to `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()`

> This lifecycle was previously named componentWillMount. That name will continue to work until version 17. Use the rename-unsafe-lifecycles codemod to automatically update your components.

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount